# Make button available after certain time?

Tags: java

So I have a method to create a button. I'd like that button to be activated every 120 (2 min) seconds. Once the button is clicked, the timer is reset.

```
addButton( new RedButton(TXT_SATURNUP) {
            @Override
            public void onClick() {
                Game.instance.showAd();
                Game.instance.wasAnswerCorrect();
            }
        });
```

If possible, I'd also like to be able to have a log message. Say...

```
if ( timerFinished ) {
    // log message to screen informing user
} else {
    // Button cannot be clicked at this time
}
```

Comment: Use some jQuery or JavaScript I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [`Timer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html). You will have to set it up with an `ActionListener` that enables your button, and you button click will have to reset your timer.

Given the interconnections I would make a new button class using the template below:

```
class TimedButton extends JButton implements ActionListener {
   private Timer T;

   // Override constructors to set up timer
   // and disable button (if/as desired)

   public void onClick(){
      super.onClick();
      setEnabled(false);
         T.restart();
   }

   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
      setEnabled(true);
   }
}
```

Then you need a method to start the timer externally, or a way to start the timer internally. You might want to avoid doing this in your constructor, as the timer may run out before you make the button is visible. It all just depends on when the button is first available.

As for the logging you can add it in the above methods or use `isEnabled()`.

Comment: New Timer class inside my RedButton class? Would I implement it inside my class where I setup the button?

Comment: If RedButton is a class you wrote and extends existing buttons then yes, you can put the Timer and methods in that class.

Comment: On the other hand, your anonymous class overrides `onClick()` in a way that would hide the new `onClick()` method, so if you continue to use that override you will have to call `super.onClick()`. I hope that is clear.